# specified duration for translate (in anim resource file) not working while starting second Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-animation

first of all I am using API 28 (Android 9.0)
I want my second activity to appear from left to right when I click the menu button on mainActivity.
I have overrided the pending transition in main activity like below:

```
startActivity(myintent);
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.no_move);
```

the left_to_right.xml with duration 100ms(that doesnt seems to be 100ms, its almost 1 second, but animation works fine):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%">
    </translate>
</set>
```

and no_move.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%">
    </translate>
</set>
```

this is my theme.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Chess" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

the activity starts how I want(animation) but the only problem is its duration.it takes like 1 second for  compelete translate.
there is no extra code to mention here, all i add was that 2 anim file and overriding pendingTranstition
plus setting windowActivityTranstition to True in themes.xml
**WHAT I WANT TO DO...**


the animation I want here is like when you click the menu button(on the top and left) in Telegram app, the menu shows up smoothly, I want something beautifule like that.
[image]
[image]

so if there is a better way to do such things or if telegram uses another way for this beautiful animation please let me know.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one `activity` with [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout) `view` for that left menu. It has open/close functions, fade effect etc. Telegram app uses their own custom view for that menu [here it is](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/ActionBar/DrawerLayoutContainer.java). You can also check source code of their activity [here](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/LaunchActivity.java) (check `DrawerLayoutAdapter`, `DrawerLayoutAdapter` variables)